# Adding image based on different Environments to which code is deployed

Tags: javascript, css, image, deployment

There is a requirement to add a watermark to all the pages in my application. This is being done now by adding the property to content in CSS

```
.content {
background-image: url("watermark_image.GIF")
}
```

All the pages in the application are under the div tage with id "content"

(The front page has been developed using *Javascript* and *CSS*)

This is working fine and the watermark is being displayed properly. This is required only while deploying into a particular environment (say X). For all others, this watermark shouldn't be shown.

As of now we are doing this by changing th CSS file to add "background-image: url("watermark_image.GIF")" for only the X environment, and leave it as it is for others. There have been scenarios where in we forget to add it and then there wouldn't be any watermark.

Can any changes be made in Javascript/CSS such that it just displays the watermark for the X environment, so that we wouldn't have to change the CSS file manually each time we do a deployment? Or is there any other way to go about it?

Comment: it can be done, but you will have to do this server side (so php for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `window.location` to check for the current domain and toggle the watermark class accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

That is dependent on your development environment.

If you are using an MVC framework, just wrap an if arround it. Here is an example with play

```
#{if mypackage.Verifyenviroment.isSpecialcase()}
.content {
background-image: url("watermark_image.GIF")
}
#{/if}
```

or in the main header page:

```
#{if mypackage.Verifyenviroment.isSpecialcase()}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@{'/public/stylesheets/specialcss.css'">
#{/if}
```